# Getting the error "no strategy registered under name: local" using passport

Tags: node.js, require, passport.js, locomotivejs

I'm using Locomotive, attempting to use passport. Still getting my head around the require function as the various guides aren't particularly clear on what I require to make things run. The following is my routes.js:

```
// MVC routes can be mapped mapped to controllers using convenient
// `controller#action` shorthand.  Standard middleware in the form of
// `function(req, res, next)` is also fully supported.  Consult the Locomotive
// Guide on [routing](http://locomotivejs.org/guide/routing.html) for additional
// information.
//
passport = require('/usr/local/lib/node_modules/passport');
passport_local = require('/usr/local/lib/node_modules/passport-local');

module.exports = function routes() {
this.root('pages#main');
this.match('login', passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',
                                                     failureRedirect: '/login' }))
}
```

And it comes up with the following error message:

```
Express
500 Error: no strategy registered under name: local

    at attempt (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/middleware/authenticate.js:237:37)
    at Passport.authenticate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/middleware/authenticate.js:244:7)
    at callbacks (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/locomotive/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:161:37)
    at param (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/locomotive/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:135:11)
    at pass (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/locomotive/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:142:5)
    at Router._dispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/locomotive/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:170:5)
    at Object.router (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/locomotive/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:33:10)
    at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/locomotive/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
    at Object.methodOverride [as handle] (/home/matt/node/hello/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/methodOverride.js:37:5)
    at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/locomotive/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you first need to register the local strategy with passport using `passport.use`, as lined out on the [github page](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local).

Comment: Embrrassed to say this is my problem ... :)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) {
 ...
}));
```

to register the strategy. If you put this in a file like `pass.js`, you will need to include it in your start-up file:

```
var pass = require('./pass');
```

I encountered the same problem when I forgot to include it in my `app.js` file. Although you won't  call 'pass' explicitly in your start-up file, passport will use it when initializing.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the local strategy installed in your local libraries. 
Npm Install passport-local